# School all kicked into touch

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, coloquialismos, solicitud-de-modismo, literatura

Un proxeneta se alegra descaradamente debido a que su amiga menor ya tiene la edad suficiente para ejercer la prostitución y dice: "School all kicked into touch".

Me topé con una noticia que se titulaba "School kicked into touch" de un ministerio que recortó los fondos para sus escuelas en entornos desfavorecidos, por lo tanto deduje que lo de arriba podría significar:

- "Mandar al diablo su proyecto educativo".
- "Posponerlo".
- "Por ahora darlo por terminado".

La metáfora deportiva a la que hace alusión "Kick into touch" en este contexto es:

- Lanzar el balón para ganar terreno cuando el equipo está bajo presión, es decir, el proxeneta la saca del problema de abuso en su casa por parte su padre o de su incapacidad para soportar la presión en su escuela para comenzar uno igualmente abusivo pero en total libertinaje.
- Lanzar el balón fuera del terreno, a saber, mandar a la escuela fuera de su entorno, alejarla(=a ella, a su amiga) del entorno escolar o sacar a la escuela de sus prioridades.

"Kick sth into touch" es detener un plan o proyecto antes que se complete.

¿Cómo digo "school all kicked into touch" en este registro coloquial, literario, de sátira, existe algo equivalente que suene gracioso?

---

EDIT:

https://onlinereadfreenovel.com/irvine-welsh/page,47,39649-skagboys.amp

- n school aw kicked intae touch
- and school all kicked into touch

Sweet sixteen, ain't that peachy keen[172]

Excerpt From: Irvine Welsh. “Skagboys.” iBooks.

“[172] «Dulces dieciséis, no son tan grandiosos». Fragmento de la letra de «I Don’t Like Mondays», de The Boomtown Rats (1979). (N. del T.)”

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skagboys
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Don%27t_Like_Mondays
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brenda_Ann_Spencer

- kick sth into touch: Remove sth from centre of attention or activity. British informal. In football and rugby, the touchlines mark the sides of the playing area and if the ball is kicked beyond these (into touch), it is longer in play.
- kick sth into touch: (Britain) to evade an issue.
- kick into touch: To cease having dealing with someone or something because of problems.
- kick into touch: To reject someone or something.

https://www.heraldlive.co.za/news/2021-08-03-hr0308-p1-lead-school-sport-kicked-into-touch/

http://news.bbc.co.uk/sportacademy/hi/sa/rugby_union/features/newsid_3461000/3461485.stm

Comment: A mí la frase "School all kicked into touch" no me parece gramatical en inglés y no la entiendo muy bien. Tampoco estoy de acuerdo con tu traducción de "school kicked into touch" como "mandar al diablo su proyecto educativo". Quizás sería interesante que enlazaras la noticia original. Por último, encontrar una metáfora deportiva en castellano que signifique algo así como "el proxeneta la saca del problema de abuso en su casa ... para comenzar uno igualmente abusivo" me parece demasiado específico y muy rebuscado.

Comment: Tampoco yo conozco esa expresión ni sé qué ha de significar solo de leerla.

Comment: "School kicked into touch"  no existe en inglés. Where did you find that??

Comment: @Lambie Añadí la información. Lo de la metáfora deportiva no es la traducción, es el contexto, una posible explicación. Aparece en Skagboys de Irvine Welsh y hace alusión a I Don’t Like Mondays de The Boomtown Rats y hay gente que dice que se vincula con un tiroreo en EE. UU. Gracias. Lo que escribí no es totalmente lo que dice el libro, solo parcial, porque el idiom lo he visto de otras fuentes.

Comment: @Lambie kick into touch is commonly used in association football and rugby football so at least in the UK it is widely understood and widely used metaphorically.

Comment: @mdewey OK. Fine. Then it has to be: The school all kicked into touch.

Answer (score 2):

Mucho mejor con las referencias añadidas. Vayamos por partes, que se trata de dos textos completamente distintos, a pesar de emplear la misma expresión idiomática.

UNO

Respecto al titular, has omitido una palabra esencial: **sport**. El titular completo reza

> School sport kicked into touch.

Es esencial por que es la que permite hacer un juego de palabras. Al incluir sport, se hace alusión a dos de los posibles significados de *kick into touch*, por un lado la jugada de rugby y por otro el significado que se le da como *idiom* o frase hecha. Ambos aparecen en la definición recogida en el Oxford Dictionary

> [kick something into touch](https://www.lexico.com/definition/kick_something_into_touch) PHRASE
>
> informal British *Reject, dismiss, or invalidate something.*
>
> Origin With reference to rugby, the ball in touch being out of play.

Si quisiéramos traducirlo al español manteniendo algún tipo de metáfora deportiva e incluyendo un juego de palabras, yo lo traduciría por

> Pena máxima al deporte escolar

Aquí establezco un paralelismo entre el penalti y la pena máxima, que son sinónimos en ámbitos deportivos. La reducción presupuestaria del 70% supone una condena a muerte de facto al deporte escolar, pues puede suponer su desaparición.

---

DOS

Respecto al texto literario tomado del libro [Skagboys de Irvine Welsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skagboys), aunque me resulta difícil entenderlo al estar escrito en jerga escocesa de los 80 y no tener el contexto completo, me da la sensación de que no hay juego de palabras ni metáfora deportiva alguna en el texto, se emplea el significado propio del *idiom*.
No sé si la chica ha dejado los estudios o la han expulsado del colegio temporal o definitivamente.

Si tuviera que traducir la frase empleando regionalismos e intentando localizarlo en un barrio obrero, tendría que usar mi malagueño natal

> ahora ke z'acabao totarmente el colehio
> ahora ke z'acabao totarmente lo d'etudiá
> ahora ke t'an largao del colehio pa siempre

Las dos primeras valen tanto si el alumno es el que toma la decisión o el que la sufre, mientras que la tercera solo sería aplicable si el alumno es expulsado por las autoridades educativas correspondientes.

Supongo que cada ciudad, provincia, región o país hispanohablante tendrá su forma propia de reflejar su acento y esa idea de abandonar la escuela.

---

Por último hay una locución verbal en español que incluye la palabra **patada**, *kick* en inglés, y que podría emplearse en este segundo contexto: **dar la patada**

> [darle a alguien la patada](https://dle.rae.es/patada)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Echarlo del lugar donde trabaja o del puesto o cargo que desempeña.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Mostrarse desagradecido con él, abandonándolo, no prestándole ayuda, etc. Tras tantos años de amistad, me dio la patada.

Si te han echado del colegio, te han dado la patada. Supongo que también puedes darle la patada a algo para indicar que lo abandonas tú pero no estoy seguro de que se use tanto.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque [*kick into touch*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/kick+into+touch) (sacar el balón de los límites) y [*patada a seguir*](https://as.com/masdeporte/2019/09/17/portada/1568740324_385176.html) (pase hacia adelante) no son lo mismo, parece que ambas expresiones se utilizan figuradamente en el sentido de [*posponer algo*](https://redautonomos.es/opinion/patada-a-seguir), quitándose el problema de encima con incierto plazo y desenlace.

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta realizada por el OP: "¿Cómo digo "school all kicked into touch" en este registro coloquial, literario, de sátira, existe algo equivalente que suene gracioso?"

Comment: @aerobiomat Podría ser posponer, sacar del centro de atención, parar de tener tratos con alguien y rechazar. Añadí la información. Pero me refería al contexto que di y no a definiciones de diccionarios, pero  igual te otorgo un +1

Comment: También evadir. Gracias.

Comment: @aerobiomat pase hacia adelante, lo saqué de otro lado, pero tampoco pienso que sea eso, es sólo otra posible explicación.